# htaccess rewrite rule for directory contains "#!"

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Have path on disk like this:  /www/snapshots/#!/contact/index.html

Need to make rewrite rule that will work with "#!" directory.

I have this rule that works with directory **/www/snapshots/contact/index.html**, but I don't know how to make it work with directory name **"#!"**

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/snapshots/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /snapshots/%1 [L]
```

Comment: `#!` is not a directory.

Comment: Take a look on image http://monosnap.com/image/UgtuLFBXnlA67SgB4Dqt5Z2GU5VKYB

Comment: Browsers won;t send anything that appears after `#` in URL